# R function does not return anticipated vector

Tags: r, function, loops

I am trying to calculate the mean (as well as other calculations) based on two groupings (phylum and environment) and I would like to redirect to output to a file. I know that the below code works.

```
new_df = myDF[(myDF$Environment=='Water_MarineTreated') & (myDF$Phylum=='Acidobacteria'),]
print(mean(new_df$pH))
```

However, because there are so many environments and numerous phyla, I feel that a function containing loops is the best way to go. I have a function that takes the name of a vector and the name of the calculation (e.g. mean, sd, var, etc...) loops through each environment and each phylum, calculates the mean pH for each permutation, adds it to a vector, and the returns the vector. Unfortunately, the return value is "numeric(0)". While this is returning what I tell it to, it is not what I want.

I think the rule is one question per post so if someone can explain why there is an empty vector that is return rather than a vector filled with the pH means, I would appreciate it. And if the rule can be bent a bit and someone can answer why "eName = numeric()" does not work, I would appreciate that too. If I place a dummy print statement inside the inner loop, when I use eName = numeric(), nothing is printed where as if I initialize Water_MarineTreated = numeric(), the dummy statement in printed.

My function and the function call can be seen below.

```
    fileName = 'mini.txt'    
    myDF = read.csv(fileName, header = TRUE, sep = ' ')
    environment = unique(unlist(myDF$Environment, use.names = FALSE))
    phyla = unique(unlist(myDF$Phylum, use.names = FALSE))

    Statistics = function(eName, funName)
    {
       #eName = numeric() #This approach does not work?!!
       for (i in environment)
       {   
          for (j in phyla)
          {   
             stats_df = myDF[(myDF$Environment==i) & (myDF$Phylum==j),]

             if (i == deparse(substitute(eName)))
             {   
                #Water_MarineTreated == c(Water_MarineTreated, funName(as.numeric(stats_df$pH)))
                eName == c(eName, funName(as.numeric(stats_df$pH)))
                print('dummy_statement')
              }   
          }   
       }   
       return(eName)
    }

    Water_MarineTreated = numeric()
    Water_MarineTreated = Statistics(Water_MarineTreated, mean)
    print(Water_MarineTreated)
```

A sample of the input looks like this:

```
Phylum pH Environment 
Acidobacteria 5.4 Water_MarineTreated 
Acidobacteria 6.1 Water_PondTreated
Acidobacteria 6.1 Water_MarineTreated 
Acidobacteria 5.6 Water_MarineTreated 
Acidobacteria 6.2 Water_MarineTreated 
Deinococcus_Thermus 4.9 Water_MarineTreated 
Firmicutes 5.1 Water_MarineTreated 
Firmicutes 5.5 Water_MarineTreated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have in the middle of the loop the line:

```
eName == c(eName, funName(as.numeric(stats_df$pH)))
```

The double equal signs `==` means to compare and return a `TRUE` or `FALSE`, it does not do any assignment.  So `eName` starts off as an empty vector and never has anything assigned to it.  This is just one of the reasons that I prefer `<-` for assignment.

Even if you switch to an assignment, the way it is now you will overwrite the value each iteration and the return value will just be the final value, not all of them.  You need something more like:

```
eName[i] <- ...
```

or

```
eName[i,] <- ...
```

Though in either of those cases it is often simpler to use `sapply` instead of a loop.

Comment: I completely see the error (== != =). I changed it and it is returning a result. Your comment about overwriting is also correct. I will either amend my code or use other suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `data.table` package offers (among other things) a very nice syntax for quickly calculating functions by groups.  Consider the following example:

```
library(data.table)

# Convert sample data to a data.table:
dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)

# Calculate the mean and median mpg by cyl and gear, where carb < 8:
dt[carb<8, # The "where clause"
   list(mpg.mean=mean(mpg), mpg.med=median(mpg)), # What you want to calculate
   by=list(cyl,gear)] # The groups go here
#   cyl gear mpg.mean mpg.med
#1:   6    4   19.750   20.10
#2:   4    4   26.925   25.85
#3:   6    3   19.750   19.75
#4:   8    3   15.050   15.20
#5:   4    3   21.500   21.50
#6:   4    5   28.200   28.20
#7:   8    5   15.800   15.80
#8:   6    5   19.700   19.70
```

Check out the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) for more.

Comment: I am pretty new to R and I was not familiar with that package. I have it installed and it does exactly what I want with very little coding. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution can be obtained using `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mtcars,.(mpg,cyl),colwise(mean))
```

For your data,if you are trying to find the mean of all columns other than Environment and Phylum (and assuming that these are numeric)

```
library(plyr)
 ddply(myDF,.(Environment,Phylum),colwise(mean))
```

Note: If you want sd, replace mean with sd.